# Setting std::ofstream to zip archived file

Tags: c++, stringstream, ofstream, php-ziparchive

I'd like to write some files directly to zip archive file (rather that creating them first on some folder and copy them to the archive on the second stage). 
Therefore, i'm wondering if there's an option to set the ofstream to point directly on the file inside the archive.

for example, say i have archive in /tmp called data.zip, and inside it there's a file data1.log

can i do something like :

```
std::ofstream ostr("/tmp/data.zip/data1.log", std::ios::binary);
```

and start pushing data using the '<<' operator ?

thanks,

Comment: No it's not possible in standard C++, you need support from some external library to handle ZIP archives.

Comment: You'll need to write your own functions (e.g. a `std::streambuf` wrapper) on top of the `lzma` or `7z` libraries.

Comment: FWIW, I know the [ZipLib](https://bitbucket.org/wbenny/ziplib/wiki/Home) library is capable of a stream to an individual file.

Answer (score 1):

> can i do something like :
>
> ```
> std::ofstream ostr("/tmp/data.zip/data1.log", std::ios::binary);
> ```
>
> and start pushing data using the '<<' operator ?

No, that's not possible.
Also note the [`std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&,const T&)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) operator is explicitly reserved for text formatted output, not to write binary data.

To achieve such you would need a [`std::streambuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf) implementation, that wraps the incoming character data to a file that is (finally?) compressed and added to  the archive.

The C++ standard library has no notion how to magically interact with binary `.zip` files.

Also what would you mean *"start pushing data"*? A `.zip` archive also contains information about particular compressed file names and their relative paths.

How would you interact with the `std::ofstream` interface to specify which file's data to add actually?

---

You should research on c++ wrappers for the [LZMA/7zip](http://7-zip.org/sdk.html) library, that let you control adding files to archives.